# MySQL join matched multiple rows as single column data

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need to figured out the mysql multiple matched rows as in single column
My First Table

```
id name
1  aaaa
2  bbbb
3  cccc
```

Second Table

```
Book_id pri_id book_name
1        1      BookA
2        1      BookB
3        1      BookC
4        2      BookA
5        2      BookB
6        3      BookA
```

I need to show the result as,
id name Books

```
id   name   booklist
1    aaaa   BookA, BookB, Bookc
2    bbbb   BookA, BookB
3    cccc   BookA
```

Somebody help how to fix this,

Comment: check for `group_concat` function.

Comment: May be help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5abe/9/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ft.id, ft.name, GROUP_CONCAT(st.bockname SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM firstTable ft
LEFT JOIN secondTable st ON ft.id = st.pri_id
GROUP BY ft.id
ORDER BY ft.name;
```

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to your answer.

Comment: you have typo `bockname` should be `book_name`